# Firebase Firestore asynchronous withConverter and references

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

All the code is written in javascript (typescript), running on a nodejs server instance. The package used to reference any Firebase code is `firebase-admin` version `10.2.0`.

I have a quite standard situation where I have a collection of products and a collection of categories. Each product must have a category.

Using firestore words, a product has a Document Reference to a category.

I'm trying now to implement the `withConverter` method in order to do some stuff to the product, one of which is to *"resolve"* the category and get some data.

Because the async nature of Firebase implementation and the synchronous way `withConverter` is, here arise the problem.

There is a solution to this? I've searched a lot on the web and seems to be no solution about, but maybe I've used google wrongfully.

Code I use

```
const converter = {
    toFirestore: (data: Product) => data,
    fromFirestore: async (snap: FirebaseFirestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) => {
        const { category, ...rest } = snap.data();

        const categoryDS = await category.get();
        const materializedCategory = { id: categoryDS.id, ...categoryDS.data() } as Category;

        return { id: snap.id, category: materializedCategory, ...rest } as Product;
    }
};
```

and for example:

```
 const doc = await firestore.collection(COLLECTION).withConverter(converter).doc(id).get();
```

Here's the error

> Types of parameters 'data' and 'modelObject' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties from type 'Product': category, name ts(2769)

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

***UPDATE:***

a sample of the product database as requested from @Prabir
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of the Firestore database from the Firebase console?

Comment: Hello @Prabir, I've edited the question with a sample from the database

Comment: Have you tried without using async?

Comment: Well yes, I've tried, but the promise does not resolve in time and the return is always undefined, which is unacceptable.

Comment: Have you followed [this document](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/global.html#FirestoreDataConverter) while creating the FirestoreDataConverter which is for firebase_admin? Also can you check your model classes if they are in accordance with the data type of the respective fields in Firestore Database?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my code. Your link to documentation does not solve the async problem inside the converter

Comment: @Valerio Facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. With the current implementation, async operations are not available